# How to use SQL TRIGGER to insert rows from another table into a new one?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

This is my create trigger statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER time_of_inserts 
AFTER INSERT ON t_workers 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
   SELECT pk_workerid, sysdate archivetime
   into t_logtable
   from t_workers
END;
```

What I want is, every time when I insert a new row into the `t_workers` table, I want to insert a new primary key (it could be unique from 1, or copying the inserted data), and the time of the insert into a new table (`T_logTable`). But I don't know how to insert this into a new table every time. You can see above, what I've came up so far.

Comment: Use sequences or generated always as, depending on your version of Oracle.

Comment: my main problem is inserting into a new table, every time it's triggered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "my main problem is inserting into a new table, every time it's triggered"

But you're not inserting, you're selecting. To insert you need to specify the `insert` keyword :)

Also, you don't want to select from the triggering table: use the :NEW namespace instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER time_of_inserts 
AFTER INSERT ON t_workers 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
   insert into t_logtable 
     values (:new.pk_workerid , sysdate );
END;
```

---

To remove the apparent confusion, SELECT ... INTO populates a local (PL/SQL) variable. It is not the syntax we use for inserting into a table.

Comment: They seem to have the word `into` in their query which I would *guess* would perform some form of insert - is that not the case?

Comment: I tought that the into should do it. But it was weird for me to not having any insert, but this is the best i've found

Comment: 'select into' statement populates variable with a value(s) from the table(s). It does not insert anything anywhere. For that we have insert statements.